# Joining multiple rows into a single row without aggregation [Oracle]

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the following query:

```
select type,
       date,
       amount
  from table;
```

And it gives the following result:

```
TYPE    DATE        AMOUNT
--------------------------------
A       30.6.2019   15
B       30.11.2019  20
C       22.12.2019  17
```

What I want to do is write a query that would return the following:

```
TYPE1     DATE1      AMOUNT1     TYPE2    DATE2      AMOUNT2     TYPE3     DATE3      AMOUNT3
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A         30.6.2019  15          B        30.11.2019 20          C         22.12.2019 17
```

The number of rows from the first query is always going to be 3 and not more than that.
I can't concatenate because I need multiple columns in the final result set. 
Can this be done in Oracle SQL without using PL/SQL?

Comment: Are there fixed no of rows or this needs to be done for millions of rows?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should've put that into the post, I'm gonna edit it. It's always going to be 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have three columns, enumerate them and aggregate:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then type end) as type1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as date1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then amount end) as amount1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then type end) as type2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as date2,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then amount end) as amount2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then type end) as type3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then date end) as date3,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then amount end) as amount3       
from (select t.*, rownum as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

If you don't know the number of columns being returned, then you need to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).